# mongodb - $sort child documents only

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When i do a find all in a mongodb collection, i want to get `maintenanceList` sorted by older `maintenanceDate` to newest. 
 
The sort of `maintenanceDate` should not affect parents order in a find all query

```
{
   "_id":"507f191e810c19729de860ea",
   "color":"black",
   "brand":"brandy",
   "prixVenteUnitaire":200.5,
   "maintenanceList":[
      {
         "cost":100.40,
         "maintenanceDate":"2017-02-07T00:00:00.000+0000"
      },
      {
         "cost":4000.40,
         "maintenanceDate":"2019-08-07T00:00:00.000+0000"
      },
      {
         "cost":300.80,
         "maintenanceDate":"2018-08-07T00:00:00.000+0000"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any guess how to do that ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Whatever order the fields are in with the previous pipeline stage, as operations like $project and $group effectively "copy" same position.So, it will not change the order of your fields in your aggregated result.

And the sort of `maintenanceDate` through aggregation  will not affect parents order in a find all query.
So, simply doing this should work.

Assuming my collection name is `example`.

```
 db.example.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$maintenanceList"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1,
      "maintenanceList.maintenanceDate": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "color": {
        $first: "$color"
      },
      "brand": {
        $first: "$brand"
      },
      "prixVenteUnitaire": {
        $first: "$prixVenteUnitaire"
      },
      "maintenanceList": {
        "$push": "$maintenanceList"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Precisely written :)